# Installing PostgreSQL for Hip-hop/HHVM

Tags: php, facebook, postgresql, hiphop, hhvm

Has anyone managed to install Postgresql for Hip-hop/HHVM?

I've have postgresql idl:
https://github.com/eantoranz/hiphop/blob/master/src/idl/postgresql.idl.php

I also have a CMake file:
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPostgreSQL.cmake

Now the problem I am running into is how to put them together. Any help will be greatly appreciated.